# Onclick display in the same page or same tab

Tags: javascript, jsp, dom-events

I have Javascript as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function redirectToPrevious(abcURL)
        {
            
            window.location.replace(abcURL);
        }
        function redirectToNext(xyzURL)
        {
            window.location.replace(xyzURL);
        }
    </script>




 <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="redirectToNext('<%=abcURL>');"/>
```

In the above Javascript, I want the URL passed which is abcurl to displayed in the same tab/page where submit button is clicked. For certain URLs get invoked or displayed under same tab in window, but for certain URLs it gets displayed in a new tab. What might be the problem?

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And what is the difference in these urls ? - are perhaps some of them in a different zone (thinking ie security settings here). Also how is the javascript invoked - e.g. from an anchor tag, or a button etc.